# Process list of object by type

Tags: c#, ninject, asp.net-web-api, nancy, onion-architecture

I have a requirement to create a Sync method.
1) On input it takes SyncRequest object.

```
class SyncRequest{
    public List<SyncObj> Objects{get;set;}
}
class SyncObj{
    public Type Type{get;set;}
    public object Object{get;set;}
}
```

2) Based on type of each object i need to use different service to proceed and the different repository to persist the data.

I.e. if i got the 3 objects with types User, User, Task. I will group them by type, and then Proceed with UserService and TaskService.

I'm trying to architect my web.api with Onion Architecture. Where DataAccess, Core, Services are separated of each other. And i want avoid swich or if's, in my code.

All ideas i came up was ugly. For example `Dicitionary<Type, Service>`, and manual casting.

I feel that Ninject might have really beatifull answer on my problem, with some factory functionality, but i can't come up with it.

Can anyone describe how this pattern should work. Or how this pattern calls, where to read.

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly, but the [Handler-Patern](http://simon-says-architecture.com/2011/09/13/the-handler-pattern/) seems to fit nicely.

Comment: do the different services (`UserService`, `TaskService`) share an interface?

Comment: [This article](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) describes the Handler Pattern that @john describes in more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all you've got is a `Type` one way or another you're going to have to use Reflection. The other question is how you're accessing the DI container (ninject kernel).

You can do something like this:

```
public interface IHandler<T>
{
    void Handle(T obj);
}

public void UserService : IHandler<User> {...}

Bind<IHandler<User>>().To<UserService>();
```

which you would then use like this:

```
foreach(var syncObj in syncRequest.Objects) 
{
    Type handlerType = typeof(IHandler<>).MakeGeneric(syncObj.Type);
    MethodInfo handleMethod = handlerType.GetMethod("Handle");

    object handler = kernel.Get(handlerType);

    handleMethod.Invoke(handler, new object[] { syncObj.Object });
}
```

As you see you'll need access to the container *somehow* to create the specific type. You can have it injected as `IResolutionRoot`.
To adhere to the Onion Layering you'll have to move the code that uses the kernel to the composition root and give it an interface...
Since you seem to know about onion layering i won't go into more detail :)

Comment: object handler = kernel.Get(handler); did you mean .Get(handlerType)?

Comment: btw. i just coded it plain-text, didn't compile it so there might be other slight mistakes.

Comment: This solution requires having factory that as constructor injection has kernel. I don't remember where, but i read that it is not a good practice to have kernel elsewhere in code rather then Resolver class

Comment: Maybe at [Mark Seeman's Blog?](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). To be better in line with "his" principles you'd have to make the factory part of the Composition root. That means the top layer - which should be the only part of the application which may know about the DI container.